# Transform an ecozone raster to vector

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, vector, reducers

I want to transform a ee.Iamge that descripbe the ecozone of a specific country to a vector. I try to reproduce this [example](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_to_vectors) but I cannot get anything else than black vector...

```js
//load the country 
var country = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'CG'));

//load the ecozones
var gez_2010 = ee.Image('users/bornToBeAlive/gez_2010_wgs84')
var country_gez_2010 =  gez_2010.select('b1').clip(country)
```

`country_gez_2010` has only one band `b1` with `int` values from 0 to 21.

```js
//construct the zones  
var zones = country_gez_2010.eq(0)
var i
for (i=1; i<21;i++){
    zones = zones.add(country_gez_2010.eq(i))
}

//Convert the ecozones to vectors.
var vectors = zones.addBands(country_gez_2010).reduceToVectors({
    'geometry': country,
    'crs': country_gez_2010.projection(),
    'scale': 100,
    'geometryType': 'polygon',
    'eightConnected': false,
    'labelProperty': 'ecozone',
    'reducer': ee.Reducer.min(),
    'maxPixels': 1e9
})

//display it on the map
var display = ee.Image(0).updateMask(0).paint(vectors, '000000');
Map.addLayer(display, {palette: '000000'}, 'vectors');
```

I'm doubting on the `zones` definition and the `reducer` selection but maybe it's something else

Comment: Please share a complete example which produces the black vector. As of now, we cannot run your code (error: "country" is not defined in this scope), so we can't help you debug it.

When you share the code, please also share the corresponding assets used in the code.

Comment: sorry, I did forget that on GEE with the name of the asset you can actually run the code. I added a simple definition of the AOI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the reducer to a more appropriate one

```
// Run reduceToVectors per class by masking all other classes.
var classes = country_gez_2010.reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
  geometry: country, 
  scale: 100,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var result = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);
Map.addLayer(result);
```

it leads to the exact definition of my ecozones

Comment: That's great. Glad you found the solution yourself.